Why is my fastrtps having errors?
matthew@MatthewGan:~$ ros2 topic echo /cmd_vel

2024-09-30 10:55:37.587 [RTPS_TRANSPORT_SHM Error] Failed init_port fastrtps_port -> Function open_port_internal

t7429: open_and_lock_file failed -> Function open_port_internal

matthew@MatthewGan:~$ ros2 doctor --report | grep fastrtps

2024-09-30 10:59:04.943 [RTPS_TRANSPORT_SHM Error] Failed init_port fastrtps_port

t7429: open_and_lock_file failed -> Function open_port_internal

rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp        : latest=6.2.7, local=6.2.7

rmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp                : latest=2.2.2, local=2.2.2

rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp        : latest=2.2.2, local=2.2.2

rmw_fastrtps_cpp                       : latest=2.2.2, local=2.2.2

fastrtps_cmake_module                  : latest=2.2.2, local=2.2.2

rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c          : latest=2.2.2, local=2.2.2
middleware name                        : rmw_fastrtps_cpp

matthew@MatthewGan:~$ ros2 topic echo /cmd_vel

2024-09-30 10:59:51.943 [RTPS_TRANSPORT_SHM Error] Failed init_port fastrtps_port

t7429: open_and_lock_file failed -> Function open_port_internal


any reason why you would not ask it here https://robotics.stackexchange.com/  (the ROS2 website points to that sister site of AU).  The experts on ROS will be there. There might be some here but your odds are a lot lower.  "open_and_lock_file failed"  smells like either a permissions error or a non existing location.
